# Wacom intuos pro not always registering two-finger taps

Tags: xorg, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos Pro 4, which is touch sensitive. Touch is mostly working except for the way it only occasionally registers two-finger touches. If I tap the tablet with two fingers it will register it click about one in every ten times or so (not always ten exactly, it varies—sometimes it's two or three, sometimes twenty). Touching hard, soft, slow, or fast all seem to work equally badly.

Is there a threshold or something somewhere I can twiddle to make it more sensitive to two-finger taps?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS / Gnome 42.9 / X11

Comment: syngestures could be a temporary workaround: https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/issues/374#issuecomment-1722645319

Comment: Thanks, I've installed that. It kinda works, in that it takes it from one in ten clicks registering to one in three or four.

Comment: Switching to Wayland fixes the problem, I'll give that a go for a bit, it introduces a bunch of other issues with screen scaling, but it might be worth the tradeoff.

Comment: Wayland should support screen scaling even better. Fractional scaling and per-monitor scaling should all work better in Wayland

Comment: The scaling works better if you don't mind that all my Qt applications (i.e. the ones I use all the time for work) look like fuzzy mush..

Comment: That is caused by QT_QTA_PLATFORM manually set to X11. Qt apps support scaling better on Wayland and should look crisp. Please make sure Qt is using the wayland platform

Comment: This would be a good fix if the application I mostly use would actually run when the QT_QTA_PLATFORM is set to Wayland. But sadly it doesn't.

Comment: If you're on KDE (not supported on GNOME yet) you can set X11 applications to "apply scaling themselves" and reboot. Then you can launch the X11 application from the command line with "QT_SCALE_FACTOR=2" or whatever (this variable does not work in .profile or .bashrc and will get reset)

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a shot, It would be worth getting over my dislike of KDE for. I'd just prefer less Qt in my life, not more.

Comment: It's like one of those puzzles where you slide one piece that then blocks another piece. Switching to Wayland fixed the touchpad issues and some other Wacom issues which was great, but Resolve (my main work application) started throwing spurious "Your GPU memory is full" errors, even when the GPU memory was completely empty. Urrrgh. Somebody throw Qt into the sea.

Comment: You must be on Nvidia. It's not recommended to use Wayland with Nvidia. This is not a Qt issue. I've had the opposite experience with Qt. GTK removed support for theming/customization and is too confusing to program with. While Qt I've gotten successfully configured to my needs and programming is a breeze with just a simple .qml file and is cross-platform. You just need to find the right config options